# Substitute for mman.h for a windows host pc

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux, eclipse-cdt, soc

I'm trying to build a project on DE1 SOC which requires me to use mmap. I am using Eclipse to code on a windows machine. I tried using this library - https://code.google.com/archive/p/mman-win32/ but when I try to add it, eclipse for some reason can't see it in the folder it is in. Is there a way to work around this? Maybe through another software or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using that library makes no sense if your target is a DE1 SoC.  That is a library for Win32. If you are cross-compiling for an embedded target, you need libraries for that target not the development host.  If the target is running Linux, then mmap is a system library and already provided.  It seems your problem (and confusion) is bigger than just getting this library to link - understanding cross-development seems to be the issue here.

Comment: What cross development tool chain have you installed? You can get WIndows hosted Linux cross-development tools for ARM-A9 from https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a/downloads.  You need to correctly set Eclipse up to use that toolchain.  You don't need this library.  Ask a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that you cannot use that library on a DE1 SoC running Linux, Eclipse is not really the issue.  Telling the compiler where the headers are and the linker where the libraries are is the issue.  It is not a "workaround", it is normal required project configuration.

[image]